# "Cancelled" or "Canceled"?

Tags: verbs, orthography, past-tense, doubled-consonants

***Cancelled*** or ***Canceled*** ? Which one is right?

> You have successfully canceled the registration

or

> You have successfully cancelled the registration

Comment: Both.  [US] canceled and [UK] cancelled.

Comment: @JoseK: This should have been written as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The past tense of [*cancel*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cancel) is strictly *cancelled* in British English (*BrE*). In American English (*AmE*), however, it is spelled (*BrE* spelt!) *canceled*. Note that *cancelled* is also acceptable in American usage. There are many other verbs whose past tenses and present participles follow a similar pattern:

> - *worship*: worshiped (*AmE*)/worshipped (*BrE*) • worshiping (*AmE*)/worshipping (*BrE*)
> - *travel*: traveled (*AmE*)/travelled (*BrE*) • traveling (*AmE*)/travelling (*BrE*)
> - *label*: labeled (*AmE*)/labelled (*BrE*) • labeling (*AmE*)/labelling (*BrE*)
> - *libel*: libeled (*AmE*)/libelled (*BrE*) • libeling (*AmE*)/libelling (*BrE*)
> - *devil*: deviled (*AmE*)/devilled (*BrE*) • deviling (*AmE*)/devilling (*BrE*)

There are some notable exceptions in which the last consonant is *always* doubled in the past tense and present participle. Examples:

> - *compel*: compelled • compelling
> - *corral*: corralled • corralling
> - *repel*: repelled • repelling
> - *refer*: referred • referring
> - *occur*: occurred • occurring
> - *demur*: demurred • demurring
> - *whip*: whipped • whipping
> - *fit*: fitted • fitting

And there also those words whose last consonant is *never* doubled when forming the past tense or present participle. Examples:

> - *differ*: differed • differing
> - *succo[u]r*: succo[u]red • succo[u]ring
> - *solicit*: solicited • soliciting
> - *gallop*: galloped • galloping

A special example is the verb *program[me]*:

> - *(AmE) program*: programed/programmed • programing/programming
> - *(BrE) programme*: programmed • programming

Comment: Note that the examples in the second list (double consonant in both varieties) are all accented on the final syllable of the basic word; and those in the third list are not.

Comment: Did you mean "worshipped"?

Comment: @Colin Fine: Indeed, they are. I didn't want to complicate my answer any further by delving into how pronunciation influences which consonants are doubled :)

Comment: I still can't believe "programed" and "programing" are valid, they look so very wrong to my eyes. (BTW, you have progaming, which, with a hyphen, is something else ;-)

Comment: @Orbling: Indeedy! Wonky, isn't it, but you still come across it here and there? Not to mention that *pro-gaming* is gradually evolving into *progaming*!

Comment: Funny that it isn't 'speled' like that!

Comment: Well, for *program*, the preferred (and by far most common) way is *programmed* and *programming*, even in American English.  Like Orbling, I thought the single-m version was actually wrong, but it's listed as the alternate in Merriam-Webster.

Comment: @John Y: Agreed.

Comment: @John Y: I knew it was supposedly valid, but every time I see it, I have trouble endorsing the reality it presents.

Comment: @JimiOke, given comments re "progaming" it isn't clear to me if you purposefully write "(AmE) program: programed/programmed • progaming/programming" or if "progaming" in that excerpt is just a typo, a dropped r.

Comment: @jwpat7: Wow, thanks! I just noticed that. Definitely a typo. Rectified!

Comment: Google's Ngram Viewer: [canceled vs. cancelled, from 1800, corpus American English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=canceled%2Ccancelled&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3). This shows `canceled` wrestling with `cancelled` between about 1940 and 1980 and finally triumphing by about 1990—but `cancelled` appears to be making a comeback this century. I'm Australian and find the `canceled` form extremely ugly, so I'm glad that `cancelled` is becoming more popular.

Comment: (For reference, their [English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=canceled%2Ccancelled&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) corpus follows a similar trend, but with `canceled` having fallen below `cancelled` after a brief supremacy, and their [British English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=canceled%2Ccancelled&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3) corpus shows no contest.

Comment: @JohnY - There's a caveat to the "double on stressed last syllable" rule, that if any form of the root is pronounced with a stressed last syllable, double the last letter for all forms. So, while "programmed" and "programming" are typically pronounced with a stressed first syllable, the word "programmable" is typically pronounced with the stress on "gram", therefore by rule the last letter of the root should be doubled everywhere.

Answer (score 17):

See the number of occurrences of *cancelled* and *canceled* from the American Corpus and British Corpus below. This supports what @JoseK wrote as comment to the question:

[Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

```
 CANCELED   3746     
 CANCELLED  640
```

[British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/):

```
 CANCELLED 1194
 CANCELED   1
```

Comment: Well we British certainly don't like the short form then!

Answer (score 5):

The American system for forming the past tense of these verbs usually follows these rules:

1. If the final vowel is long, leave a single consonant, as otherwise a double consonant would convert the vowel to short: *reviled, amazed, completed*.
2. Else, if the stress is on the final syllable, double the final consonant, same as the British system: *compelled, deferred*.
3. Else, if the final vowel is *e*, we leave it single: *traveled, canceled*.
4. Else, it varies. For the vowels *a* and *i*, I think it's standard to leave the vowel single: *kidnaped, worshiped*. But to me that looks like it's a long vowel, and I think it looks better with the consonant doubled, which I believe is also acceptable: *kidnapped, worshipped.*

Comment: When I was a kid in (American) school, I was taught that if the final vowel is short, double the consonant before adding -ed or -ing. This rule made sense to me as the resulting word then followed the usual rules for determining if the vowel is long or short. To my eyes, "canceled" should be pronounced "kan-seeld". This is the rule I followed until Microsoft spell-check came along and told me it was wrong. I see from Google ngrams that "cancelled" was more popular than "canceled" until circa 1985, so I wonder if Microsoft spell-check is, in fact, dictating the future course of the language!

Comment: @Jay: While I believe it's possible that spell checkers can and are having an effect on spelling, I am confident the specific case of *canceled* is more that Microsoft was just following (and thus possibly reinforcing) the prevailing American conventions. You can find *canceled* as the preferred (with *cancelled* as acceptable alternate) in many print dictionaries that predate the rise of Microsoft.

Comment: The identity of the vowel letter in the last syllable doesn't make that much of a difference. Doubling is usually absent in American English in *totaled* and *imperiled.*

Answer (score 1):

It can be both, 'canceled and 'cancelled'. But to me, 'cancelled' looks way better than 'canceled'.

P.S.-Nice play on the words 'canceled' and 'cancelled'!!!!! Seems quite a tongue twister!