# Why "controlled" not "controled"?

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, historical-change, doubled-consonants

Unlike British English and other varieties, American English does not double the letter "l" in words such as "traveled", "canceled", etc. However, it does with the word "controlled". Is there any logical explanation for this contradiction?

Comment: Ah, see [Colin Fine's comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9192/cancelled-or-canceled/60951#comment15174_9199) and [Jasper Teal's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9192/cancelled-or-canceled/60951#60951) beneath the following question: [“Cancelled” or “Canceled”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9192)

Comment: @sumelic: excellent reference.